# Set property according to value returned by other property

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [simpleUpload.js](http://simpleupload.michaelcbrook.com) script. I'm trying to customize the error messages. The [documentation](http://simpleupload.michaelcbrook.com/#errors) says that:

> *The type of error can be accessed using error.name and its message at error.message*

Given the following callback:

```
error: function(error){
    //upload failed
    $('#progress').html("Failure!<br>" + error.name + ": " + error.message);
}
```

as explained in the docs, one of the possible errors is 'InvalidFileExtensionError' which is returned by `error.name`while the relative message is given by `error.message`

Now I would like to change the text of `error.message` but I don't understand how to 'associate' `error.name` with `error.message` and set the new message. Kind of:

```
if error.name = "InvalidFileExtensionError" then error.message = "Bad extension"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an object of names with your new values like this

```
var obj = {"InvalidFileExtensionError": "Bad extension", 
           "otherError" :"other message" };
```

And then access like this

```
 obj[error.name]
```